# When and why should we use Event type in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, object

```
private class EarthquakeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Event>{

  @Override
  protected Event doInBackground(String... urls) {
    // Perform the HTTP request for earthquake data and process the response.
    Event result = Utils.fetchEarthquakeData(urls[0]);
    return result;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Event result){
    // Update the information displayed to the user.
    updateUi(result);
  }

}
```

Why use the type **Event** in this code snippet? Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any object for the third type of AsyncTask generic type. For From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:
>
> 1. **Params**, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
> 2. **Progress**, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
> 3. **Result**, the type of the result of the background computation.

For the following class:

```
private class EarthquakeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Event>{
  ...
}
```

it means that the class is using **String** as params, **Void** as progress (which means that it ignore the progress), and **Event** as the result when the process in `doInBackground()` method is finished.

the callee code for `EarthquakeAsyncTask` need Event as its parameter:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Event result){
  // Update the information displayed to the user.
  updateUi(result);
}
```

so, obviously, the EarthquakeAsyncTask need the Event as the third type.